# bash script for start mining process after disconnection -linux -ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, connection

I am currently using ethminer on ubuntu 20.04. My internet is not bad however for shorts periods of time I lost connection causing mining to stop. I would like to build a bash script to retry connection whenever the mining stops. Appreciate any guides on this

the command line used to mine is something like this:

```
ethminer -G -P stratum1+ssl://wallet_adress@pool
```

In the past I have written a bash script to do some ping analysis for my isp, I am very noob using bash scripts. I will appreciate if you can give some hints for starting this.

Comment: Couldn't you just add a while loop to this?

Comment: can you give an idea of how condition for this while looks like?

Comment: I don't know the `ethminer` command, is it a command that only terminates when the connection is lost? If so, couldn't you just do while true so that the command is always executed when internet goes down?

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @wxz, for helping me figure this out.

```
#!/bin/bash
y=1
while [ y ]
do
  ethminer -G -P stratum1+ssl://wallet_adress@pool
done
```